# What's wrong with this input form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner to the ruby/rails language, I only learn by creating things that interest me so I have set out to create a simple bank system.

I haven't got very far, as I'm getting the following error:

```
ndefined method `text_field' for nil:NilClass
```

Line 7 of this code:

```
  <%= form_tag('/deposit') do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :dval %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
```

Here's my bank class

```
class BankController < ApplicationController
def initialize
    @balance ||= 0 
end


  def deposit
    @dval ||= 0
    @balance = @balance + @dval
  end

  def withdraw
  end
end
```

I want dval to be the number the user wants to deposit, so if they put 10 and submit the form, it will add dval (10) onto the balance variable.

Any indication as to how I can do this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your form_tag have an `<% end %>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your form should be

```
<%= form_tag('/deposit') do%>
  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field_tag 'dval' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= submit_tag "Submit"%>
<%end%>
```

Your controller should be

```
class BankController < ApplicationController
  def deposit
    @dval = params[:dval].to_i 
    @balance = @balance + @dval
  end
end
```

Documentation for [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)

Documentation for [text_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag)